# System.TypeLoadException at OnConfiguring method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a simple context class that maps to a local SQL Server database.

```
public class LojaContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
                {
                    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=LojaDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
```

When I run the app create an instance of it, I get this error when the method `UseSqlServer` runs:

*System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'Clone' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.'*

I already googled and apparently this error happens when the connection string is wrong. However, I already tested it opening a connection with a `SQLConnection` object and it's fine.

Comment: That error would usually imply that the .dll found at runtime is not the one that was compiled against, Unless you're doing something really weird.Id suggest trying to work out what dll is being loaded at runtime and why ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by installing the latest version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. I was using version `1.1.0` and I had the latest version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`. Now both are 2.1.4.